# How to upload objects to Google Cloud Storage using Python Script?

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I know how to upload the objects using gsutil in command prompt, however, it doesn't seems flexible enough for me. So I am wondering how could I upload the objects to Google Cloud Storage using Python scripts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the [Google Cloud Client Library for Python](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/) in particular, the client interacting with the [Storage API](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/storage-client.html).

You can install the libraries using `pip install`:

```
pip install --upgrade google-cloud
```

Uploading a file would go something like:

```
from google.cloud import storage

client = storage.Client(project='project-xxx')
bucket = client.get_bucket('bucket-xxx')
blob = bucket.blob('test.txt')
blob.upload_from_filename('test.txt')
```

Comment: Hi @atsang01 you can also consider using the "subprocess" module, which allows you to run shell commands from within a python script, as mentioned in my response to a (loosely!) related question here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44975080/is-there-any-advantage-to-using-gsutil-or-the-google-cloud-storage-api-in-produc/45012186#45012186)  This can be useful because it lets you use gsutil commands directly, which is sometimes a little more convenient. 
 Happy coding!