# Upload a file to Google Storage via Python given the URI

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I would like to upload a file to google storage just given the storage uri in the format `gs://<bucket_name>/<blob_name>`.

I'm aware of the possibility to upload a file in Python using a code like

```py
def upload_file(filepath, bucket_name, blob_name):
   client = storage.Client()
   bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
   blob = bucket.blob(blob_name)
   blob.upload_from_filename(filepath)
```

But what I actually would prefer is a function that just gets the local filepath and the google storage uri, similar to gsutil's copy command: `gsutil cp <filepath> gs://<bucket_name>/<blob_name>`. So, something like that:

```py
def upload_file_to_uri(filepath, gs_uri):
   pass
```

Do I have to write a regex command to parse the bucket and blob name from the given uri, or exists already a more elegant solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the python client library, it is necessary to upload files like you mentioned in your question. Nevertheless, you can perform something like below

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("gsutil -m cp gs://my-bucket-name/* /home/<username>/rawdata/", shell=True)
```

You can find a similar answer at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44975080/is-there-any-advantage-to-using-gsutil-or-the-google-cloud-storage-api-in-produc/45012186#45012186).

Comment: This works only on Cloud Run and Compute engine/GKE.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it currently exists in the Python library. You'll need to parse out the bucket and blob name.

That said, you're welcome to use gsutil's implementation. It's under the Apache license. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/blob/c84f8487460596c1bf7f049bb31714262bf223ca/gslib/storage_url.py#L184

It may be slightly more complicated than you need, since it supports generation numbers, wildcards, and path delimiters, but it works.